# Retrieve boolean value from selected array object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

**Objective**

I'm trying to create a form that will display different dropdown(select) lists based on a single first choice of "Plan Type" e.g.("Basic", "Standard", "Deluxe").

If a user selects "Basic", then the user can choose from a new dropdown list called "Option A". If they select "Standard" or "Deluxe" then they receive "Option B".

**Edit to Objective**

I guess I just really need to have the isOptionA or isOptionB available for consumption in my view.

**Requirement**

The user can only see the options that they have selected, I do not want to show disabled fields of any kind (reason: its a bad experience for basic users, IMO).

Also, the options in all dropdowns are not to be changed by the user at any point in time.

**Past Research**

I've crawled all sorts of sites, including SO. None of them can help me put it all together.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <select id="planType" data-bind="options: planTypes, value: selectedPlanType, optionsText : 'name', optionsValue : 'id', optionsCaption : 'Select your Plan'"></select>
</div>
<div data-bind="if: isOptionA">
    Option A Available!
</div>
```

**Knockout JS**

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.planTypes = [
        { id: 0, name: 'Basic', optionA: false, optionB: true },
        { id: 1, name: 'Standard', optionA: true, optionB: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'Deluxe', optionA: true, optionB: false }
    ];

    self.selectedPlanType = ko.observable();
    self.isOptionA = ko.computed(function(){
        //pass the currently selected plan type's boolean for optionA to
        //'isOptionA'
    });
    self.isOptionB = ko.computed(function(){
        //pass the currently selected plan type's boolean for optionB to
        //'isOptionB'
    });

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Please view my js fiddle here and lend help if you can.

http://jsfiddle.net/winsconsinfan/9jqgazfx/9/

Comment: I know i don't have the subsequent options represented, at this point their data is irrelevant. I really just want to return isOptionA and isOptionB as either true or false and see it update in the view

Comment: Also, forgive my naivete in using SO or JSFiddle, This is my first question on the site and my first fiddle as well.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9jqgazfx/11/?

Comment: This might be a little crude, but it should get the point across: http://jsfiddle.net/9jqgazfx/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to not set the `optionsValue` in your binding.  By setting the `optionsValue`, the value gets projected to the property of the selected option.  In this case, `selectedPlanType` will be the `id` if the corresponding selected option.  It would make everything easier to just use the option itself so you don't have to figure out which was selected again.

```
<select id="planType" data-bind="options: planTypes,
                                 value: selectedPlanType,
                                 optionsText: 'name',
                                 optionsCaption: 'Select your Plan'">
</select>
```

Given now that the `selectedPlanType` will now hold the actual `planType` object that was selected, it's just a matter of checking the selected plan type's option value.

```
self.selectedPlanType = ko.observable(); // now a planType object, not id
self.isOptionA = ko.computed(function(){
    var selectedPlanType = self.selectedPlanType();
    return selectedPlanType && !!selectedPlanType.optionA;
});
self.isOptionB = ko.computed(function(){
    var selectedPlanType = self.selectedPlanType();
    return selectedPlanType && !!selectedPlanType.optionB;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9jqgazfx/10/

---

Otherwise, if you need that select to actually use the id, you'll need to make some adjustments to you figure out which planType object is selected from the id.  A computed observable will help here.

```
<select id="planType" data-bind="options: planTypes,
                                 value: selectedPlanTypeId,
                                 optionsText: 'name',
                                 optionsValue: 'id',
                                 optionsCaption: 'Select your Plan'">
</select>
```

```
self.selectedPlanTypeId = ko.observable();
self.selectedPlanType = ko.computed(function () {
    var selectedPlanTypeId = self.selectedPlanTypeId();
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.planTypes, function (planType) {
        return planType.id == selectedPlanTypeId;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9jqgazfx/14/

Comment: Dumb guy question, what is the !! operator for?

Comment: It's just a way to convert an expression to a boolean value.  e.g., `!!undefined` -> `!true` -> `false`

Answer (score 0):

```
var viewModel = function(){
var self = this;
self.planTypes = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Basic'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Standard'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Deluxe'}
];

self.selectedPlanType = ko.observable();
self.isOptionA = ko.computed(function(){
    return (self.selectedPlanType() != null)? self.selectedPlanType() != 0 ? true :false :false;
});

self.isOptionB = ko.computed(function(){
    return (self.selectedPlanType() != null)?self.selectedPlanType() == 0 ? true :false :false;
});
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The above code should help you out. All we are doing is looking if the selected option has a value and is equal to something you want . ie standard, basic etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/9jqgazfx/13/